# How to access the function underlying a @declared_attr?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

so I have a requirement to introspect the function underlying a `@declared_attr` decorated `Base.__tablename__()` method. I was wondering how this can be done. I've looked at the `declared_attr` class, and it seems to inherit from `property`, but it doesn't seem to be possible to do the same thing you'd do with ordinary properties:

```
class Example:
    @property
    def example(self):
        pass

Example.example.fget  # <function __main__.Example.example(self)>
```

Because when you access the `@declared_attr` decorated attribute from the class you immediately get the function result, rather than a property object:

```
class ExampleBase:
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()


ExampleBase.__tablename__  # "examplebase"
```

So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can circumvent invoking the descriptor by accessing the descriptor object through the class' `__dict__`:

```
In [17]: ExampleBase.__dict__['__tablename__'].fget
Out[17]: <function __main__.ExampleBase.__tablename__>
```